# Variable inside handlebars expression

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've got a specific element I want to retrieve from an array, `{{page.myArray}}`.

I have the index of the element in a variable, `{{my-index}}`, but I can't just plug in `{{page.myArray.[my-index]}}` or `{{page.myArray.[{{my-index}}]`.

How do I go about doing this? I've tried out some things from SO and the Handlebars docs, but I can't for the life of me come up with a solution. Hopefully, a kind and generous soul can give me a helping hand here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is a 'no' as Handlebars syntax don't permit the nesting of statements.
However, you can write a custom handlebars helper to achieve the same.

Considering your JSON structure as,

```
{
  "my-index": 1,
  "page": {
    "myArray": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  }
}
```

Your template can be written as below, which is the helper(`indexOf`) call itself.

```
{{#indexOf page.myArray my-index}}{{/indexOf}}
```

And the helper definition would be,

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('indexOf', function(array, value) {
  return array[value];
});
```

This will print `b` as the output as its in the index position `1` of the array `myArray`.

Tested using http://tryhandlebarsjs.com.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is working perfectly, thank you! Can I bother you with one more question? If myArray is an array of objects, how do I change the above to access those elements? I've tried changing the helper to `Handlebars.registerHelper('indexOf', function(array, value, object-key) {
  return array[value].object-key;
});` and `{{#indexOf page.myArray my-index object-key}}{{/indexOf}}` , but it's no bueno.

Comment: Can you please post your sample JSON here?

Comment: Say I'm using the same helper I mentioned above, but my expression is `{{#indexOf page.myArray my-index key1}}{{/indexOf}}` and my JSON looks like this `{
  "my-index": 1,
  "page": {
    "myArray": [
      {"key1": "value"}
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is very late, but you can do this now in handlebars with the **lookup** helper. You would use it like this

```
{{lookup page.myArray my-index}}
```